# Ubuntu 16.04 MySQL_InnoDB

Tags: 16.04, mysql

[image: About Mysql Engines And DB]

[image: mysqlv ersion]

I have a problem about MySQL.
I want to use MySQL_InnoDB but I can't.
I have already installed about InnoDB.
What's wrong with me?

Ubuntu version is 16.04 And Mysql version is 5.7.15.

I need your help.

Answer (score 0):

https://ckon.wordpress.com/2015/08/06/put-mysql-functions-back-into-php-7/

PHP7.* Not provide MySQL_* functions.

Solved